# exec() (or like functions) pass back error output

Tags: php, error-handling, exec

I can pass back output of the executed script, but I get no error output if the script errors out.

```
// This is a file that doesn't exists, for testing
$command = './path/to/non/existing/script.sh';

$commandOutput = exec($command, $commandOutput); // works but no error output
//passthru($command, $commandOutput); // works but error output was 127 not file not found
//$commandOutput = escapeshellcmd($command);
echo "The Output:\n|".$commandOutput."|\n";
var_dump($commandOutput);

The Output:

||
```

I would like the output of the error message:

```
The Output:

|file not found|
```

How or what function/parameter would do this?

Comment: btw: `$commandOutput = exec(..., $commandOutput);` the assignment will overwrite any changes made to $commandOutput "within" exec(), thus you won't get more than the last line of the output. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redirect stderr to stdout so exec() et al will fetch error messages by appending `2>&1` to your command.

see http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: if I use this will I loose my server internal logging for the error as well?

Comment: "server internal logging" ? Do you mean syslog?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ob_start();
passthru($command);
$content_grabbed=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $content_grabbed;
```

The second parameter is for the return status of the command sent to the system.

Comment: I got an exit code of 127 when trying to run the command eee using passthru, but no error information relating to it from the shell. If you want to detect errors then you need to pass the optional return var(s) when using this function.

Comment: exec() and passthru() both only "watch" the stdout of the spawned process. So if exec() didn't return the desired output passthru will not "print" it either and the output buffer can't fetch it.

Comment: @pharalia what are the 'optional return var(s)' and how do I set them?

Comment: declare a variable and pass it as the second argument to passthru(), it's passed by reference and will be populated with the exit code of the executed application